# Webmin Failed to save MySQL server options

Tags: mysql, webmin

I am having this error on trying to update mysql config from webmin "Failed to save MySQL server options :" mysql is working fine, phpmyadmin is working fine. i can stop and start server from webmin. but i cannot make any changes to the config. Where are these changes stored. I have checked the /etc/my.cnf and the config in webmin does not match that. so where is webmin storing this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

bug for a webmin, need to config /etc/mysql.cnf manually in xwindow/console